# Scipy stats.probplot not returning r^2 value bug?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, spyder

I'm currently plotting the normal proability plot of a set of feature variables in a data matrix X using scipy.  However, the module I'm using is not returning my r^2 value.  Here's my simple code:

```
Data_Matrix=pd.read_csv('My csv')
My_datum=My_Data.as_matrix()
#loop through all feature variables
for i in range(My_datum.shape[1]):
    #just a simple print line for the column index and its shapiro test 
results
    print(i)
    print(a)
#plot    
pplot=stats.probplot(My_datum[:,i],dist='norm',fit=True, plot=plt )
    a=sp.stats.shapiro(My_datum[:,i])
```

I've tried using the same line on some simpler numpy array, but to no avail.  I'm working the Ipython console on spyder 3.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `r^2` and why does it have to return that value?

Comment: R^2 = Goodness of fit

Comment: r^2 is the coefficient of determination, and is the "strength" of the linear predictor as Stuart Buckingham said!  Let me know if I can provide more detail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probplot returns the R value already. You just need to square it to give you R^2.

```
(slope, intercept, r) = stats.probplot(My_datum[:,i], dist='norm', fit=True, plot=plt)
R_squared = r**2
```

Comment: thanks for the reply!  I'm a bit confused though, I'm getting an error where I don't have enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2?)

Comment: Ahh, can you try just setting plot to True: i.e. `(slope, intercept, r) = stats.probplot(My_datum[:,i], dist='norm', fit=True, plot=True)`

Comment: Sadly that did not work, although if I just initialize two tuples instead of three to hold my values it works!

Comment: That is strange. According to here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.probplot.html it should return a tuple with 3 values. I also got it to work on my computer with a generic list for the dataset.

Comment: i'll keep playing with it, but thanks for answering my question!

Answer (score 1):

So this is a little weird but it returns a list of tuples. You actually just need to extract the second tuple from the list by indexing the probplot function. You'll need to unpack the tuple to then square it.

```
slope, intercept, r = stats.probplot(My_datum[:,i], dist='norm', fit=True, plot=plt)[1]

r2 = r**2
```